# Trying to figure out how to calculate mean in mtcars using loop's

Tags: r

I am very new to R and was looking for some answers. I am trying to figure out how to calculate mean of all variables from mtcars data set,using any loop function . Any help/suggestion would be of great help

Answer (score 2):

We can use `colMeans`

```
colMeans(mtcars)
```

Or with `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
mtcars %>%
     summarise_all(mean)
```

---

If we need a loop,

```
sapply(mtcars, mean)
```

Or using the `for` loop

```
v1 <- numeric(length(mtcars))
for(i in seq_along(mtcars)) v1[i] <- mean(mtcars[[i]])
```